# Find an enclosed area in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

So I'm programming a game in Processing where a character moves in 4 directions, and wherever it moves, it stores its coordinate in a 2D array on a 500x700 dimension.

If the character moved to coordinate (5,10) per say, then array[5][10] will be set to 1. Otherwise, 0.

What I want to find is an rectangular enclosed area in this array. How will I even go on about doing this? I have no idea and I've tried everything by trial and error but could someone help me out? Thank you in advance!

Edit ****

So let's say I have a 2D array of 10x10:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

My question is, when there is a surrounding "rectangle" of 1, how will I search for that?

For example:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

the 1's that start from [1][1] should be detected as a rectangle of area 42. 6 in width and 7 in length.

What I've tried was to run through the array with a for-loop then whenever there is a 1, searched the length and height, and determined if existed on the other side, the same length at position "n" away. Is this appropriate to do so? What would be a more efficient solution?

Comment: Please post what you've tried and why do you think it fails. Also, what do you mean by *rectangular enclosed area*?

Comment: How is this array set up? is each row a sub-array?

Comment: @Bryan: It's a 2D array. So basically you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer[][] intArray = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

    int highestFreq = 0;
    List<Integer> freqList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(Integer[] intArrays : intArray ){
        List<Integer> arrays = Arrays.asList(intArrays);
        int freq = Collections.frequency(arrays, 1);
        if(freq > highestFreq){
            highestFreq = freq;
        }

        if(freq > 0){
            freqList.add(freq);
        }

    }

    Integer count = 0;
    for( Integer ints : freqList.subList(1, freqList.size()-1 )){

        if(ints.equals(freqList.get(1))){
                count += 1;
        }

        if(count == freqList.size() - 2){

            System.out.println(highestFreq * freqList.size());
                    //prints 48

        }
        };

}


}
```